# How to render a state abbreviation in Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Folks, this has to be easier than I've made it. In a front-end template, how do you grab a state abbreviation from a customer's address in Craft Commerce?

```
{$ set addresses = craft.commerce.customer.addresses $}
{% for address in addresses %}
  <-- this is where I want to show the abbreviation -->
  {{ address.state.abbreviation }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer on Slack from Stephen Callendar.

```
{% set addresses = craft.commerce.customer.addresses %}
{% for address in addresses %}
  {% if address.getState() %}
    {{ address.getState().abbreviation }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```